# How to programmatically call the touch screen calibration tool in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, touchscreen

There is a panel in Windows 10 called *Tablet PC Settings* which has a button that allows a user to calibrate the touch input.

I would like to programmatically call this calibration tool, but can't find an API to do it.

Does anybody know if there is an API for this?

Thanks!

Comment: is it a process? you might want to start that process manually using `Process.Start()`

Comment: when the Calibration tool is running, open the task manager to see what applications are running, if you're find the calibration tool as a process, Just call Process.Start("Process_name_here"). If it is running from a service, then you have to find out which service it uses and how to call the specific method

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

As Alex and kowsikbabu suggested, the easiest way is to invoke the MultiDitiMon process with the -touch or -pen argument

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\MultiDigiMon.exe", "-touch");

Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\MultiDigiMon.exe", "-pen");
```

Comment: Hey Ivan.

And after running this command, how can we simulate touching the screen we want?!

Thank you!