# How to programmatically open Windows "Tablet PC Settings" dialog?

Tags: c#, windows, touchscreen, tablet-pc

I want to open this dialog in my C# program:

[image: Tablet PC Settings]

Is there an Win32 API or exe I could use?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260847/how-to-programmatically-call-the-touch-screen-calibration-tool-in-windows-10) asked for configuration only. I would like to show the whole dialog.

Comment: That's a traditional Control Panel applet, isn't it (not a modern settings applet)? I think you just open the correct `.cpl` file. Take a look at https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/06/open-windows-control-panel-applets-directly/

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks, but `tabletpc.cpl` opens "Pen and Touch" dialog, not "Tablet PC Settings" dialog?

Answer (score 1):

rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL tabletpc.cpl @1
the " @1" tells it to open tablet pc settings vs pen and touch dialog

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).